# How to optimize a docker image?

Tags: docker

I am building a webapp with several docker images via docker-compose.
One of the Docker images is webserver_web.
The size of the image (~1.2 GB) looks pretty big to me and, I wonder what tricks I can apply to reduce the size.
I suspect that I'm not using the Dockerfile efficiently.

Observations regarding the layers size:

- The webserver_web image is using `FROM python:3.7.6` for the first layer.
- The size of the `python 3.7.6` image is 919MB
- There are 34 layers (column "IMAGE") in the history
- The first 18 layers have a total size of ~918MB (which fits the size of the python 3.7.6 image)
- The 19th image corresponds to the second command in the Dockerfile ("MAINTAINER User4 ")
- the first 18 images are coming from the first command in the Dockerfile ("FROM python:3.7.6")
- the shear size of the image (~80%) comes from the python image
- The contribution of the base image to the overall image size: ~80% (918 / 1136.64)
- The size of the image webserver_web: 1136.64 MB (1.11*1024)
- 58.2MB is coming from the need to install `sudo, vim, and nano` into the container:
  `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim nano sudo`

Here are the image sizes, the Dockerfile, and the layers of the docker image.

**Any ideas what can be done to reduce the size of the webserver_web Docker image?**

**Is size of more than 1GB acceptable for a docker image?**

Thanks,
Avner

---

The image sizes:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
...
webserver_web                latest              ec306049da3e        15 minutes ago      1.11GB
python                       3.7.6               879165535a54        3 months ago        919MB
```

The Dockerfile:

```
cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7.6
MAINTAINER User4 <user4@gmail.com>

# Create the group and user to be used in this container
RUN groupadd flaskgroup && useradd -m -g flaskgroup -s /bin/bash flask

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim nano sudo

# http://gbraad.nl/blog/non-root-user-inside-a-docker-container.html
# Add user flask to sudoers
RUN echo "flask ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/flask && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/flask

# Create the working directory (and set it as the working directory)
RUN mkdir -p /home/flask/app/web
WORKDIR /home/flask/app/web

# Install the package dependencies (this step is separated
# from copying all the source code to avoid having to
# re-install all python packages defined in requirements.txt
# whenever any source code change is made)
COPY requirements.txt /home/flask/app/web
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY . /home/flask/app/web

RUN chown -R flask:flaskgroup /home/flask

USER flask
```

Layers of the docker image (with size for each layer):

```
avner@avner-ThinkPad-P51:~$ docker history webserver_web
IMAGE               CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
0688e195012d        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  USER flask                   0B                  
3052d2e91fd0        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c chown -R flask:flaskgroup /home/f…   35.3MB              
81a5cf0a37b9        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:668861ff8c7f55004…   35.3MB              
24341ee304ae        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r req…   64.2MB              
925e12e74fe8        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:4e7a69dabf52b355…   1.07kB              
0419bbb589d3        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /home/flask/app/web   0B                  
b87691531f4a        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /home/flask/app/web         0B                  
251001545b6f        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c echo "flask ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:A…   30B                 
980fc4c0dd9c        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   58.2MB              
9015bd3d1e3b        2 minutes ago        /bin/sh -c groupadd flaskgroup && useradd -m…   334kB               
7ad23eec9ab4        2 minutes ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  MAINTAINER User4 <user4@g…   0B                  
879165535a54        3 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B                  
<missing>           3 months ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex;   wget -O get-pip.py "$P…   6.34MB              
<missing>           3 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256…   0B                  
<missing>           3 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=ht…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=20…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/bin  && ln -s idle3…   32B                 
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex   && wget -O python.tar.x…   91MB                
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.6     0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   17.9MB              
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/…   0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   510MB               
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   145MB               
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   17.5MB              
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   16.5MB              
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           4 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a5ec219cbfc4e0c31…   114MB
```

Comment: [Big size of Python image in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060871/big-size-of-python-image-in-docker) suggests the base `python` image has been large for a while now; [How do I reduce a python (docker) image size using a multi-stage build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543834/how-do-i-reduce-a-python-docker-image-size-using-a-multi-stage-build) has one approach to reduce it; and the [Docker Hub `python` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) discusses image variants.

Comment: Your Flask application doesn't need `sudo`, `nano`, or `vim` and you can probably delete that `apt-get install` line from your Dockerfile with no consequence, but the really big layer at the end of the `docker history` output is from the `python` base image and not your code.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time python docker images are big. If you want to slim down your images you can use [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). But it will slow your build time. Also you can reduce the layer in the image (eg. Don't use multiple `RUN` statements, instead use once and do all your execution in one statement). But it will make nearly all the caching mechanism of docker useless. And it will increase build time significantly.

**TL;DR;**

Python images are big. Bigger is faster. Smaller is slower. 1GB is not so large for a python image.

I highly recommend this links for python docker images:

- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/
- https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/slimming-down-your-docker-images-275f0ca9337e

---

I was referring build time in **"Bigger is faster. Smaller is slower."**. I recommend this [article](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/14/docker-image-size.html) that is about docker image sizes. Actually it is not a big overhead for network to have big images (images with many layers) as it looks. It will be an overhead only the first time uploaded it. After that all little changes will be small due to layer caching in registry/server. If you use multistage, pruning/purging or squeezing your image will be smaller. But when you change it even a little bit, it will upload nearly all layers from beginning (Because there is few number of layers in image). So if you change your images often the bigger images can reduce your bandwidth usage. But if you do not change your images often, make it small as possible (Remove unused tools in the end, stage your sections, use minimal number of statment in last stage).

Comment: "Bigger is faster. Smaller is slower" - I am mostly concerned by a remote machine pulling 1 GB over the Internet from my Docker registry.
**Can you elaborate why bigger is faster?** (in terms of pulling the data over the network)

Comment: I was referring build time in there. I highly recommend this [article](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/14/docker-image-size.html) that is about docker image sizes. Actually it is not a big overhead for network as it looks. It will be a overhead only the first time uploaded it. After that all little changes will be small due to layer caching.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a lot of options , at the end you start with a 919 MB image, all the layers before `MAINTAINER User4 ...` are python:3.7.6 layers . Perhaps to install only vim or nano , not a big win .